# texstudio: show line numbers in editor

Tags: texstudio

How do I show line numbers in the editor? According to the picture in the doc (e.g. about bookmarks) there should appear by default.

I'm using Texstudio version 2.7, win8.1.

Comment: i don't use texstudio, but u can check out view option of the studio.

Comment: This is bad usability if someone has to ask how to do something as trivial as turning on line numbers!

Comment: Very similar, I cannot find any option to show column count.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Under preferences, tick the 'Show Advanced Options' checkbox in the bottom left of the window, several new menu items are made available, including 'Adv. Editor'.

Under 'Adv. Editor', under Appearance section, there is a drop-down box 'Show Line Numbers':

[image]

Comment: Finally. I read about the advanced options, but somehow I missed the checkbox, and I thought they talked about an old version. Thanks for the image.

Comment: And "Preferences" means "Options > Configure Texmaker". This setting is amazingly convoluted for being so basic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am wondering why designers of Texstudio thought that showing the line numbers is an advanced option in an advanced editor...

Comment: I would tend to agree frankly.

Comment: Update! I was looking for this too, and it has now been moved to the normal "Editor" settings. Finding it by using the filter function works too.

Answer (score 22):

In newer versions (at least in TeXstudio 2.12 to 4.3.1 on Win10&11)
you find it in "Editor" (not any more "Advanced Editor")

Step by step:

- Options
- Configure TeXstudio
- Use Editor options ("Editor" on the left)
- Activate line numbers (select "All lines and numbers" in drop down menu "Show line numbers")

[image]

alternatively you could use the "(option filter)" to find it faster (Type it in the current GUI-language, not in english)

Comment: @auditiv02 For current Versions there is no need any more to activate "Show Andvanced Option"-Box for enabling line-numbers. However I generally recommend it to activate it.

Answer (score 10):

OK, here are the complete instructions for turning on line numbering for the linux version of TexStudio:
Options > Configure TexStudio (then tick **Show Advanced Options** box in **lower left corner of window**. At that point a new entry will appear **Adv. Editor**. Select that. On the third line down in the new window will be an option to turn on line numbering.