# Where's Adv. Editor for me to turn line number on at texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

My Texstudio is 2.7.0 portable, running on Windows 8.1. The problem is that I can't turn on the line number display. I consult [texstudio: show line numbers in editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183801/texstudio-show-line-numbers-in-editor), but there's no Adv. Editor in my preference and after searching through all the options, I find nowhere to turn on the line number indicator. 
The picture below gives more details.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Bottom left corner of the *Configure TeXStudio* window (your second screenshot), there is  a checkbox where it says *Show Advanced Options*. Having checked that, Adv. Editor will appear in the list right above.