# TeXstudio - editor window with fixed width

Tags: texstudio, editors

I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.8 and I was using the software with the standard configuration and options.

I wanted to show line numbers in editor window, so I followed this link: [texstudio: show line numbers in editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183801/texstudio-show-line-numbers-in-editor).

For this, it's resolved as I want. However, after this my editor window fixed the text width until the vertical line in image above, and I don't know how to return to a variable width controlled by the entire size of the window.

I think that I did this accidentally, but I didn't find the option in "Configure TeXstudio" menu to correct this. Can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to your texstudio preferences in the "adv. editor" tab (you might have to activate that advanced options are shown), then you can select under `line wrapping` how the lines should be wrapped.

I guess what you are looking for is "Soft line Wrap at Window Edge"?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is! Thanks a lot, my problem was solved!

Comment: @ThiagoKuerten You're welcome!